# How to deal with time it takes to finish something in REST?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Using Jersey/JAX-RS I have a get handler that contains code to copy a large file to another location. I want to be able to go to a URL and be able to see the current state of the copying (i.e. time elapsed). How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which side? The sender or the receiver?

The sender could expose a link or something, as part of the request.

You could arguably do something like

POST receiver/foo/incoming

```
<incoming-foo>
    <link rel="status" uri="sender/foo/abc/status">
</incoming-foo>
```

receiver might '201 Created' or '303 See Other' sender to the URI receiver/foo/1

at this time, a

GET receiver/foo/1

might simply return the provided status link, or embed it in the representation:

```
<foo>
    <status>incoming</status>
    <link rel="status" href="sender/foo/abc/status" />
</foo>
```

GET sender/foo/abc/status

Might return, at this time, "pending" or "queued" or something like that.

...

Then, sender is free to

PUT receiver/foo/1

```
<foo>
    <content>...</content>
</foo>
```

During the PUT, async GET to the services can still GET the status from the origin service, which might now be "transmitting" or include the bytes/total, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would assume since it is a long running operation, having the initial POST return a 202, with the Location header or a link in the content body to the status page of the copy operation would be a good approach. The client can then GET the status URL periodically and, when the server completes the copy, the GET can return a link using a 303 or some mechanism to locate the newly created file.

Hope that helps!